# Bring to front FAB on Android 4.4 or lower

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-design-library

mi problem is that fab_bar button is placed behind the RecyclerView. This only happens in Android 4.4 or lower, in newest Android releases I don't have any problem.

I do not have enough reputation to post pictures so I leave the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5hYd.png

Is there any solution to this or is a bug?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_shadow_elevation">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit_light"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/fab_bar_shadow_elevation"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_atrib_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_shadow_elevation">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_atrib_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit_light"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/fab_bar_shadow_elevation"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your code, `FAB` comes before `RecyclerView`, so `RecyclerView` override `FAB`.

Comment: Many thanks! I took several days mulling over this nonsense. I thought the declaration order did't matter in layouts...